# How to open second page div in first page click function

Tags: javascript, jsp

Is it possible to open second page particular div content in first page click function ,i need to open particular div content only all other divs are hide

Here is my click function of first page:

```
function quiz(){
            $("#secondlist").show();
            window.location = "second.jsp"


        }
```

This is my list:

```
<div id="sample" class="content" style="display: none">
<ul class="tabs">
<li id="tab4"><a href="javascript:quiz()">Quiz</a></li>
</ui></div>
```

and second page div:

```
<div id="secondlist" style="display: none">
<h3>sample</h3>                         
</div>
```

Could you please help anyone:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change window location you will clear the page.

Instead do

```
function quiz(){
  $("#sample").load("second.jsp #secondlist",function(){
    $(#secondlist").show();
  }); 
}
```

Alternative is this (but then display = none needs to be removed)

```
window.location="second.jsp#secondlist"; // note the lack of space before #
```

Lastly please change

```
<li id="tab4"><a href="javascript:quiz()">Quiz</a></li>
```

to

```
<li id="tab4"><a id="quiz" href="second.jsp#secondlist">Quiz</a></li>
```

and the code to

```
$(function() {
  $("#quiz").on("click",function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); // stop the link from changing page
    var href = this.href.split("#"), fragment = href[0]+" #"+href[1];
    $("#sample").load(fragment,function(){
      $(#secondlist").show();
    }); 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: thanks for your quick comments mplungjan but it is working partialy some other divs also opening in second page.How to remove that,please help....

Comment: Like this? _$("#sample").load(fragment,function(){
      $("div").hide();$(#secondlist").show();
    });_